read a value from config file, inside a jade file
I have a home.jade file in a node.js project, and a lot of other .jade files that extend it.
In home.jade, I want to read a value from a config file. I don't wand to need to update all render calls in order to make sure the value is accessible.

Please provide more information. What format is the config file in? What are you using to compile? What do you mean by render calls? Please include a [mcve] using paired-down versions of the files you describe.
